# rails 3.1, Installing capybara-webkit, Failed to build gem native extension, what to do?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-plugins, capybara, capybara-webkit

I am trying to install capybara-webkit (0.8.0), but I get the error below, can any body help, I am on ubuntu 11.10.

> Installing capybara-webkit (0.8.0) with native extensions 
>   Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native
>   extension.
>
> ```
>     /home/sam/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/bin/ruby extconf.rb  /usr/bin/qmake /usr/bin/make cd src/ && /usr/bin/qmake
> ```
>
> /home/sam/Documents/RoR/course_builder/CDPATH=/ruby/1.9.1/gems/capybara-webkit-0.8.0/src/webkit_server.pro
>   -spec /usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/linux-g++ -o Makefile.webkit_server /usr/bin/make cd src/ && make -f Makefile.webkit_server  make[1]:
>   Entering directory
>   `/home/sam/Documents/RoR/course_builder/CDPATH=/ruby/1.9.1/gems/capybara-webkit-0.8.0/src'
>   g++ -c -pipe -O2 -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -DQT_WEBKIT -DQT_NO_DEBUG
>   -DQT_WEBKIT_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_NETWORK_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_SHARED -I/usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/linux-g++ -I. -I/usr/include/qt4/QtCore -I/usr/include/qt4/QtNetwork -I/usr/include/qt4/QtGui -I/usr/include/qt4/QtWebKit -I/usr/include/qt4 -I. -o RequestedUrl.o RequestedUrl.cpp make[1]: g++: Command not found make[1]: *** [RequestedUrl.o] Error 127
>   make[1]: Leaving directory`
>   /home/sam/Documents/RoR/course_builder/CDPATH=/ruby/1.9.1/gems/capybara-webkit-0.8.0/src'
>   make: *** [sub-src-webkit_server-pro-make_default-ordered] Error 2
>
> make cd src/ && make -f Makefile.webkit_server  make[1]: Entering
>   directory
>   `/home/sam/Documents/RoR/course_builder/CDPATH=/ruby/1.9.1/gems/capybara-webkit-0.8.0/src'
>   g++ -c -pipe -O2 -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -DQT_WEBKIT -DQT_NO_DEBUG
>   -DQT_WEBKIT_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_NETWORK_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_SHARED -I/usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/linux-g++ -I. -I/usr/include/qt4/QtCore -I/usr/include/qt4/QtNetwork -I/usr/include/qt4/QtGui -I/usr/include/qt4/QtWebKit -I/usr/include/qt4 -I. -o RequestedUrl.o RequestedUrl.cpp make[1]: g++: Command not found make[1]: *** [RequestedUrl.o] Error 127
>   make[1]: Leaving directory`
>   /home/sam/Documents/RoR/course_builder/CDPATH=/ruby/1.9.1/gems/capybara-webkit-0.8.0/src'
>   make: *** [sub-src-webkit_server-pro-make_default-ordered] Error 2
>
> Gem files will remain installed in
>   /home/sam/Documents/RoR/course_builder/CDPATH=/ruby/1.9.1/gems/capybara-webkit-0.8.0
>   for inspection. Results logged to
>   /home/sam/Documents/RoR/course_builder/CDPATH=/ruby/1.9.1/gems/capybara-webkit-0.8.0/./gem_make.out
>   An error occured while installing capybara-webkit (0.8.0), and Bundler
>   cannot continue. Make sure that `gem install capybara-webkit -v
>   '0.8.0'` succeeds before bundling.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to that log you don't have g++ (the gnu c++ compiler installed) which you'll need to build the gem's native extension. You'll also need the qt development headers

Comment: Thanks, can you please point me to where to install the g++ ? I came to unix from .NET world for the sake of RoR, I still need to learn new things, your help is highly appreciated.

Comment: I found t his thread, I think its close to the solution:
http://forums.opensuse.org/english/get-technical-help-here/applications/451945-bin-sh-g-command-not-found.html

Comment: on ubuntu it would seem that the package is just called g++. Install it with something like `apt-get install g++`

Comment: how can I know which version of g++ is required for capybara-webkit (0.8.0) native extensions ? apt-get install g++ will install g++ 4.6

Comment: it worked! I've installed g++ and, yes, native extension is installed now :-)

Comment: Yay! Glad you found the answer!